# Use results proven in a library (Coq)

Tags: coq

How do I use results proven in a given library? For example, I want to use `Lemma peano_ind` from the library `BinInt`. I write this in CoqIDE:

```
Require Import BinInt.
Check peano_ind.
```

and get a "The reference peano_ind was not found in the current
environment." error. I am also not able to use it with `apply` during a proof.

However, it should be there, because with a `Locate Library BinInt.` I see that Coq can find the file BinInt.vo, and when I open the file BinInt.v I can see `Lemma peano_ind`.

I have this exact problem both on a Debian 9.0 + CoqIDE 8.5pl2 and on a Windows 10 + CoqIDE 8.6.

---

All of this because I wanted to do induction over the integers. A different solution for that would also be nice, but I'm still frustrated by my lack of ability to use some previously proven results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `BinInt` library has one of *several* `peano_ind` definitions in different submodules for different types. You can find these using `Locate peano_ind`:

```
Constant Coq.NArith.BinNat.N.peano_ind
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is BinNat.N.peano_ind)
Constant Coq.PArith.BinPos.Pos.peano_ind
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is Pos.peano_ind)
Constant Coq.ZArith.BinInt.Z.peano_ind
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is Z.peano_ind)
```

Then you can use these qualified names, for example:

```
Check Z.peano_ind.
Z.peano_ind
     : forall P : Z -> Prop,
       P 0%Z ->
       (forall x : Z, P x -> P (Z.succ x)) ->
       (forall x : Z, P x -> P (Z.pred x)) -> forall z : Z, P z
```

You can also `Import Z` to allow to use the unqualified name `peano_ind`.